# Filter and foreach java 8 stream as parallel

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, stream, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to iterate through list of objects. but it is taking too long I've tried below code and I want to make it modern and scalable by increasing the thread pool.

```
result.getObjectSummaries().parallelStream().forEach((objectSummary) -> {
                    if (objectSummary.getLastModified().after(dateBeforeMp)
                            && objectSummary.getLastModified().before(threadStartDate)) {
                        String correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "js" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        if(1==loadFileToSnowFlake(appId, tenantId, objectSummary.getKey(), correlationId)) {
                            logger.info("File loaded for the tenantId {} and fileName: {} ", tenantId, objectSummary.getKey());
                            sendMessageToSQS(appId, tenantId, bucketName, objectSummary.getKey(), correlationId);
                        }
                    }
                    count.incrementAndGet();
                });
```

I'm not finding a proper way to do this. As of now it works well. My intension is s3Object lists 1000 files in a single request I want to assign job to each thread inside a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Java stream `parallelStream()` uses an internal, fixed size thread pool that you cannot modify on the go, (maybe not at all)

You can leverage the CompletableFuture api, and use a custom thread pool to execute your task, e.g.:

```
// Different flavors of thread pools available
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
Stream.of(1000, 2000, 3000)
    .forEach(i -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // Long running tasks
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Result
        System.out.println(i);
    }, executor));
```

In the above, the stream will be iterated in a single thread (it would be sufficient for ~100,000 items, for even larger batches you can add `.parallelStream()` to the mix), and execute the actual work in a thread specified in the executor.